# php form data not being submitted in database correctly

Tags: php, html

my database name is login and has a table called users three columns:name,id and post. when I hit the submit button, the id is incremented and a new record created but no actual data is created in these fields. please help

```
 <?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="login";

$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection error:".$conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo 'connected successfully';
}
#defining varriables
$user_name = isset($_POST['user_name']);
$post = isset($_POST['post']);

#connect this to login details and pick the userrname

$sql="INSERT INTO posts(user_name,post)
VALUES('$user_name','$post')";
if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "your post was published";
}?>
```

form data

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="post"/>
    <input type="submit" name="post to cdrone"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: You are using isset() wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns a boolean value. So your `$user_name` and `$post` variables are each going to be set to either `true` or `false`, rather than the values posted from your form.

Consider setting the values conditionally, depending on the value of `isset()`.
I prefer using the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to include some validation:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

  $user_name = !empty(trim($_POST['user_name'])) ? trim($_POST['user_name']) : false;
  $post = !empty(trim($_POST['post'])) ? trim($_POST['post']) : false;

  if (!$user_name) {
    echo "User Name is required.";
  } elseif (!$post) {
    echo "Post is required.";
  } else {
    // insert into database
  }

}
```

> The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.